# How to use systemd-cryptsetup generated units

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, kde, manjaro

I am trying to automatically mount an encrypted usb device, whenever it is attached. Therefore I added a new entry in `/etc/crypttab`:

```
ext /path/to/dev /path/to/key bitlk,noauto
```

This will let systemd-cryptsetup-generator create a new service unit for decrypting the device, whenever it is attached.

But for some reason this service is not enabled and has to be started manually. Moreover, it cannot be enabled via systemctl, since the [Install] section is missing.

Adding the section seems tedious. What is the best workflow to automatically start these services?

I am using manjaro 22 (plasma KDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These generated units are actually added as dependencies for the **.device** unit that would be created after unlocking. For example, the generator extends `dev-mapper-ext.device` with a dependency on `systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service`, therefore anything that depends on this .device will cause it to be automatically unlocked.

```
> tree /run/systemd/generator*
/run/systemd/generator/
├── dev-mapper-archive2.device.requires/
│   └── systemd-cryptsetup@archive2.service -> ../systemd-cryptsetup@archive2.service
├── dev-mapper-data.device.requires/
:   └── systemd-cryptsetup@data.service -> ../systemd-cryptsetup@data.service
```

This means that an /etc/fstab entry referencing `/dev/mapper/ext` (or rather, the .mount unit generated from that fstab entry) will, indirectly, depend on systemd-cryptsetup@ext and will cause the device to be unlocked whenever it needs to be mounted (either on boot or manually with `systemctl start /mnt/ext`).

```
myth> systemctl list-dependencies -a /mnt/hdd
mnt-hdd.mount
● ├─dev-mapper-data.device
● │ └─systemd-cryptsetup@data.service
● :   └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1eb9bbbb\x2dcb37\x2d4fab\x2dad12\x2da512fed4a0a9.device
```

As with most of systemd boot process, the design here is not event-based "hotplug" unlocking of cryptsetup devices but dependency-based "on demand" unlocking.

(You can still implement "hotplug" unlocking and mounting by adding dependencies on the mount to the raw .device unit, e.g. making "dev-sdb.device" want "mnt-ext.mount" would cause the disk to be unlocked and mounted as soon as it is connected.)

Note that in KDE, mounting disks interactively through Dolphin should not require systemd-cryptsetup as UDisks2 itself takes care of unlocking LUKS or other devices before mounting them.

---

You can manually create dependencies using `systemctl add-wants`, which does roughly the same as `systemctl enable` except using command-line arguments instead of [Install] instructions.

```
# systemctl add-wants foo.service systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
```

Though if your service depends on the device being available, then it is better to be direct and depend *on the device* instead of any implementation detail:

```
# systemctl add-wants foo.service dev-mapper-ext.device
```

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation, which sheds a lot of light! As for KDE, I get prompted for the password, when I interactively access the usb device in dolphin. Unfortunately it cannot remember the password, which renders the workflow a little bit tedious, since I have to open a wallet and copy-paste the string. When working with luks, it can remember the password, therefore it looks like this bug is till present https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452303. Running `systemctl add-wants...' on the transient unit won't work. 
I am still a little bit puzzled, about what's the best workflow.